# Reference request for some result of de Bruijn on zeros of some holomorphic function

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory

In a [video lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t908N5gUZA0) on Youtube, ''Vaporizing and freezing the Riemann zeta function'', Terry Tao states that ''*de Bruijn proved that if for some $t_0$ the zeros of $H_{t_0}$ are contained in the strip $\lbrace x+iy, |y|\leq y_0\rbrace$, then the zeros of $H_t$ are all real for $t\geq t_0 + \frac{1}{2}y_{0}^2$*'', where $H_{t}(z)=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{tu^2}\phi(u)\cos (zu) \mathrm{d}u$ and $\phi$ is some exponentially decaying function.

However, Tao did not provide any reference for this result. So does anyone know where i can find this result ? Which paper of de Bruijn and which lemma/theorem/corollary ?

**ADDENDUM 1:** In the same video (min 37-38), Tao states an even more interesting result of De Bruijn:

``*De Bruijn showed that if for some real $t_0$ the zeros of $H_{t_0}$ are contained in the horizontal strip $\lbrace x+iy: |y|\leq y_0 \rbrace$, then for all $t>t_0$, they will be contained in a narrower strip \begin{equation} \lbrace x+iy: |y|\leq (y_{0}^2 - 2(t-t_0))^{1/2}_{+} \rbrace,\end{equation} where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$*.''

Recall that $H_{0}(z)=\frac{1}{8}\xi(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{iz}{2})$, where $\xi$ denotes the Riemann xi function. Since $\xi(s)\neq 0$ for $\Re(s)\geq 1$, we can take $t_0 = 0, y_0 = 1, t=t_{0} + \frac{y_{0}^2}{2} - \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is an arbitrarily small positive number, and deduce that all the zeros of $H_t$ must be real for $t>0$. This implies that if all zeros of $H_t$ are real if and only if $t\geq \Lambda$, then $\Lambda \leq 0$ (the Riemann Hypothesis !)

In other words, **De Bruijn proved the RH, but didn't realize it !** This strengthens the need for a complete reference of de Bruijn's results that Tao quoted.

**ADDENDUM 2:** The de Bruijn result only entails that $\Lambda\leq 1/2$, as explained by @Conrad in the comments.

Comment: Thanks Todd Trimble for including the video link.

Comment: You get $t \ge .5$ since $y_0=1$, so you just noticed Bruijn's conclusion that $\Lambda \le .5$

Comment: I don't understand the claim but you can't prove the RH from elementary results ($\approx$ not based on the primes) about $\theta(x) = \sum_n e^{-\pi n^2 x}$'s Mellin transform because the RH fails for things like $\zeta(s,1/4)$ (no Euler product) whereas things like $\sum_{m=0}^3 i^m\theta(x+im/4)$ have quite the same properties as $\theta(x)$

Comment: the claim is wrong as noted; it is just an arithmetic mistake, while the true result is (unsurprisingly) the one obtained by De Bruijn in 1950, that $\Lambda \le .5$, $\Lambda$ being what is now called De Bruijn-Newman constant and which needs to be zero for RH to hold (best known upper bound, 0.22 afaik, lower bound zero being very recent)

Comment: @reuns, the fact $y_0 \leq 1$ is a consequence of the Euler product. So the above argument does apply properties of primes in some way. BTW, some experts now believe it is the non-vanishing of $\zeta(s)$ for $\Re(s)>1$ that is more fundamental than the Euler product. So it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Conrad, i don't see any ''arithmetic mistake'' here. The quoted result indeed entails some bound on the de-Bruijn-Newman constant, AND also a bound on $y_0$, as it clearly states. The argument here is on the bound it provides for $y_0$ as $t$ becomes large.

Comment: By definition for $t \ge \Lambda$, $H_t$ has only real roots so the imaginary part of those will be zero, but what that has to do with proving RH? You need the roots of $H_0$ to be real...

Comment: @Conrad, by definition, the de Bruijn-Newman constant $\Lambda$ is the minimal real number such that the zeros of $H_t$ are all real for $t≥\Lambda$. Since the quoted result of de Bruijn entails that the zeros of $H_t$ are all real for $t>0$, what does that say about $\Lambda$ ?

Comment: The quoted result implies only $\Lambda \ge .5$ which is the original result from 1950; note that $y_0=1, t = 0+ \frac{1}{2}=.5$; the result shows that the strip narrows with increasing $t$ and gets to $0$ at $.5$; a polymath project reduced it to $.22$ as of 2018

Comment: The narrower strip depends on $t$ by definition (maybe the formulation is confusing as it's from a talk rather than a peer reviewed paper, so it's looser) but it clearly states that given $t_0, y_0$ for each $t>t_0$ the strip where the roots of $H_t$ can have imaginary parts narrows to $|y| \le |y_t|$ with $y_t$ given by the formula mentioned; to get to $y=0$ you need $t = .5$ and that was precisely de Bruijn conclusion in his paper

Comment: $t_0=0, y_0=1, |y| \le ((1-2t)_{+})^\frac{1}{2}$, gives $|y| \le 0$ for $t \ge .5$ so you are perfectly right, any choice of $t$ greater or equal to a half will do

Comment: $(1-2t)_{+}$ is $0$ if $t > .5$ so the square root makes sense for all $t$ real and de Bruijn proved only that $\Lambda \le .5$ which was still a remarkable result since it took 58 years to supersede afaik; nothing to do with proving RH I am afraid; it's a good idea to actually read his paper as someone linked it here and it treats other functions too

Comment: @Conrad, you you are right, i now see.